# Pycharm code completion don't works when importing MongoClient while vscode works fine

Tags: python, pycharm, pymongo

Good morning. As per the subject, importing MongoClient from pymongo, pycharm doesn't have suggestion for its derived objects.

[image: No suggestion for Pycharm]

Tho the very same source, with same interpreter (both system wide, and virtualenv one) with vscode works like a charm.

[image: Suggestions works with VScode]

I already tryed :

1. Restoring PyCharm default settings
2. Upgrading and reinstalling to latest version
3. Destroy and recreate virtualenv, and re-pipping the module

The only module i have this issue with is pymongo, other ones, builtins, pipped or my own's just work fine.
Googleing resulted pointless, anyone can give me some direction?

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
db = client.testdb
```

to

```
db = client['testdb']
```

Comment: This answer was reviewed in the [Low Quality
Queue](https://stackoverflow.com/help/review-low-quality). Here are some
guidelines for How do [I write a good
answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Code only answers are
**not considered good answers**, and are likely to be downvoted and/or deleted
because they are less useful to a community of learners. Please [edit] your
answer to include an explanation of how and why the code solves the problem,
when it should be used, what its limitations are, and if possible a link to
relevant documentation.